# Numerical scheme for convex optimization

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given $(e_n)_{-N\le n\le N}\in\mathbb R^{2N+1}$ and $-1<x<1$, solve

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\max_{(q_n)_{-N\le n\le N}\in\mathbb R^{2N+1}_+}~ \sum_{n=-N}^N (e_n-\log(q_n))q_n \\
\mbox{s.t.} &&\quad \sum_{n=-N}^N q_n=1 \mbox{ and }  \sum_{n=-N}^N nq_n/N=x.
\end{eqnarray}

My question is whether we have (very efficient) packages (C++ or Python) to solve numerically this convex optimization problem? E.g. processing time less than 0.1 second with $N=100$. The motivation comes from my previous question, and I need to solve 40,000 optimization problems of this type to construct a discrete Markov martingale.

Any answers and comments are highly appreciated!

**My thoughts :** Introduce the Lagrangian multipliers and define

$$L(q_{-N},\ldots, q_N,\lambda_1,\lambda_2):=\sum_{n=-N}^N (e_n-\log(q_n))q_n+\lambda_1(\sum_{n=-N}^N q_n-1)+\lambda_2(\sum_{n=-N}^N nq_n/N-x).$$

Setting $\partial_{q_n}L=e_n-\log(q_n)-1+\lambda_1+n\lambda_2/N=0$, $\partial_{\lambda_1}L=\sum_{n=-N}^Nq_n-1=0$ and $\partial_{\lambda_2}L=\sum_{n=-N}^Nnq_n/N-x=0$, one has $q_n=\exp(e_n-1+\lambda_1+n\lambda_2/N)$ and thus

$$\sum_{n=-N}^N \exp(e_n-1+\lambda_1+n\lambda_2/N)=1\quad \mbox{and}\quad \sum_{n=-N}^N \exp(e_n-1+\lambda_1+n\lambda_2/N)n/N=x.$$

We obtain finally

$$\sum_{n=-N}^N \exp(e_n+n\lambda_2/N)(n/N-x)=0.$$

Let $z:=\exp(\lambda_2/N)$, one has

$$\sum_{n=-N}^N \exp(e_n)z^{n}(n/N-x)=0=\sum_{n=-N}^N \exp(e_n)z^{n+N}(n/N-x).$$

Define $A_k:=\exp(e_{k-N})(k/N-1-x)$ for $0\le k\le 2N+1$. Then solving the above opitmization problem is equivalent to search for the strictly positive root of the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}A_kz^k=0$. Is there any quick solver for this?

Comment: What have you tried? 

Here are a couple of things to try:

- https://cvxopt.org/
- https://www.cvxpy.org/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978754/whats-a-good-convex-optimization-library

Comment: @EdgarCosta I have very few knowledge of programming. I read the instructions but I do not find the corresponding package. Most are linear or quadratic problems, see https://cvxopt.org/examples/index.html#tutorial-examples

Comment: I would ask on scicomp.SE instead of here.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem very quickly. From $\partial_{q_n} L=0$, we have
$$q_n(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = e^{e_n - 1 + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 n/N}.$$

We know that $q_n$ has to sum to 1 (the first constraint), so  we can eliminate $\lambda_1$:

$$q_n(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \frac{e^{e_n - 1 + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 n/N}}{\sum_{n'} e^{e_{n'} - 1 + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 n'/N}}= \frac{e^{e_n + \lambda_2 n/N}}{\sum_{n'} e^{e_{n'}  + \lambda_2 n'/N}}\equiv q_n(\lambda_2).$$

This determines the solution vector  $\{q_n\}_{n}$ up to a single coefficient $\lambda_2$, which will be determined by your second constraint.  You can find $\lambda_2$ using a 1-dimensional root-finding algorithm,  i.e.,  satisfy $f(\lambda_2)=0$ where
$$f(\lambda_2) := \sum_n q_n(\lambda_2)  n/N - x$$
You can use for instance Newton's method, which should take milliseconds.